Kubuntu 24.04 runs only in recovery mode
I updated my computer from Ubuntu 23* to the Ubuntu 24.04. I'm in recovery mode right now. I cannot run Ubuntu without recovery mode and I don't know how to fix it.
Can you help me?
I tried: reinstall ubuntu-drivers, apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*', searched some errors in syslog - but there is nothing, boot-repair.

Edit the file /etc/default/grub and modify the lines like this:
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"

Then run sudo update-grub.

Thank you! But I solved it of installation new Ubuntu. There was a little problem with my data. Solved: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515217/kubuntu-24-04-apps-arent-show-in-tray-panel/1515278#1515278

The OP already resolved the issue but I'm leaving another approach for future reference.
I also recently upgraded to UbuntuMate 24.04 and the laptop would only boot in recovery. I have a dual GPU setup with an AMD integrated graphics GPU + Nvidia RTX 3060. Under additional drivers the most recent option (already installed) was nvidia-driver-535. However, using aptitude, I was able to remove to remove that and install nvidia-driver-550. That resolved the problem for me.

Problem was back when I updated additional drivers in software-properties-gtk. X.Org works amazing but NVIDIA driver not works.
I had to run into recovery mode and change driver into X.Org.
