Kubuntu 24.04 - Apps aren't show in tray (panel)
All icons are in tray (wifi, notifications, sound, CTRL+C, ...) but there are not any apps (Pidgin, Thunderbird). And it's new instalation of Ubuntu 24.04 (with my old profile data). I tried create new profile - everything is ok. I tried copy some configuration files but without success. So what must I do?

SOLVED: Any problem was in one of files in folder .config. I don't know which. I deleted (and backuped) all files. Ubuntu created new config settings. I had to set all config but it works!!! Pidgin works. Thunderbird needed "Reset preferences" of SysTray-X: https://github.com/Ximi1970/systray-x
